# Cover letter vs. "Introduce Yourself"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

In the context of Stack Overflow Jobs is the "Introduce Yourself" box expected and accepted in lieu of a cover letter?

My internalization of job search advice over the years makes me feel like my application is naked if I do not include a cover letter with a résumé.  However, Stack Overflow Jobs does not have an explicit facility for providing a cover letter.

My response to the "Introduce Yourself" box (as it is presented), would probably be less formal and shorter than a cover letter.  I do not necessarily mind those differences, but it also makes it feel like something different than a cover letter and I want to be sure to provide a complete application.

I could include a cover letter as the first page of the résumé PDF, but I don't know if that would be a good thing for finding a way to provide a cover letter or a bad thing because the PDF is now more than just a résumé.  If I were to do this, I would still have a short-form response to "Introduce Yourself" and then a more traditional cover letter with the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your note. You raise a good point re: "Introduce Yourself" is less formal and shorter than a cover letter." We're considering updates to the employer view so that your intro is presented as an intro, and not as a cover letter.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Answer (score 4):

'Introduce Yourself' *is* your cover letter. It was historically always called this but it changed to the current copy a few months back. 
FWIW In the database it's stored in the `CoverLetter` column and it's presented to the employer as a cover letter in other parts of the system.

Comment: If for all intents and purposes, it *is* a cover letter, why would it be represented as anything else?

Comment: It's *just copy*...