# Allow resizing the cover letter textarea

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

So per Stack Overflow Jobs' glossary, [*introduce yourself*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344577/cover-letter-vs-introduce-yourself) is a cover letter. I use Word to write my cover letter, and I like to review my letter one last time before submission. However, the field is not resizable. Here's an example of a letter of how a 400 words letter looks like:

[image]

I suggest we add `resize: vertical` to textarea:

[image]